# Webpack can do multiple entries, how can I do the same thing for resolve.alias?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, preact

Webpack can do multiple entries like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
    }
};
```

But how can I create two different **alias** for pageOne and pageTwo?

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
    }
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            aliasForPageOne: ?, // What should I do?
            aliasForPageTwo: ?,
        },
    },
};
```

I ask this question because I want to use `react` for pageOne, but alias `react` to `preact` for pageTwo(I want even alias node_modules react component to preact)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible by your approach. `alias` values have to be strings based on the [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). If you really have two separate pages, you could try Webpack's [multiple configuration ability](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations).

In your case that means something like the following:

```
// note the exported array
module.exports = [
{
  entry: {
    pageOne: './src/pageOne/index.js',
    }
},
{
  entry: {
    pageTwo: './src/pageTwo/index.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': 'preact'
    }
  }
}
];
```

Another approach would be to directly import `preact` in your scripts on pageTwo, but based on your approach I think this isn't a valid way in your situation.